# Heads-up: StackExchange introducing mandatory arbitration clause

Tags: discussion

Just a heads-up: the new (2018) terms of service include a mandatory arbitration clause, which is generating some pushback from the community:

[A new (2018) update to our Terms of Service is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309746/a-new-2018-update-to-our-terms-of-service-is-here)

At present you can opt out, but only by writing to StackExchange by snail mail:

https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/public

> If you don’t want to be bound by the arbitration and class-action
>   waiver provisions in this section, you must **notify us in writing
>   within thirty (30) days** of the date that you first accept these Public
>   Network Terms (unless a longer period is required by applicable law),
>   and then you must litigate any disputes against us in accordance with
>   the "Assignment and Jurisdiction" section below. Your written
>   notification must be mailed to us at **Stack Overflow, Attn: Legal
>   Department, 110 William Street, Floor 28, New York, NY 10038.** If you
>   do not notify us in accordance with this paragraph, you agree to be
>   bound by the terms of this section, including, without limitation, the
>   arbitration and class-action waiver provisions, and also including
>   such provisions in any modifications we make to these Public Network
>   Terms after the date of your first acceptance. **Such notification must
>   include: (i) your name; (ii) your email address and mailing address;
>   and (iii) a statement that you do not wish to resolve disputes with us
>   through arbitration or waive your ability to participate in a class
>   action.**

EDIT: StackExchange are [reviewing whether they can provide an online opt-out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309797/were-examining-the-implementation-of-arbitration-in-the-2018-tos-update).